# White foam when cooking chickpeas, what to do with it?

Tags: chickpeas

When cooking chickpeas, what should one do with the white foam?

I've heard that some remove it as it comes. But is this really necessary, since the water is filtered from the chickpeas when they are done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Partial answer: The white foam certainly seems to provoke overboiling, which might be ONE reason people skim it off before leaving an open pot of chickpeas to cook unattented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I remove the foam when cooking chickpeas?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8041/should-i-remove-the-foam-when-cooking-chickpeas)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The white foam is a 'scum' that is formed as protein is released from the chickpeas. Yes, that is the term that is used. Scum.

This can be skimmed for aesthetic reasons - it sticks to the pot, or overboils, etc...

You are absolutely right, though, that if the chickpeas are rinsed after, then this is washed away.

If you are draining and pureeing, it will just incorporate into the dish.

Totally an aesthetic choice in my experience.

Similar to meat protein scum, referenced ([What is this in the beef stew?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/87858/what-is-this-in-the-beef-stew/87861#87861))